# What does naturally mean here?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, supergravity

We often cross the sentence

> "Kahler geometry emerges *naturally* in sugra".

I have always wondered what does this mean; actually what does *naturally* mean in that sentence?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Consider including reference to quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Naturally" means in this case that the Kähler manifold appears out of the other ingredients of the theory without us putting in a Kähler structure by hand. *"Natural"* in such mathematical contexts often means that there is no *choice* for a certain structure, it just appears from the other parts of the theory.

In this case, the Kähler geometry appears out of the potential on some complex scalar fields. These fields were introduced without the slightest idea of a Kähler geometry, but it turns out that their potential has the right form to be interpreted as a Kähler metric on a manifold for which those fields provide the coordinates. That is, the target space of the collection of scalar fields carries a *natural* Kähler structure in the sense that it is prescribed by the theory already - there is no choice of this structure to be made once the fields and their potential are fixed.

Comment: But you didn't mention anything concerning Supergravity. Where does Supergravity take place in our description above?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: It's the "potential on some scalar fields". The potential the appears in supergravity on some complex scalars in a supermultiplet is of the required form for a Kähler metric. Generic potentials on complex scalars as they appear in other places are *not* Kähler metrics, but supergravity constrains the potential such that it is always amenable to be interpreted as a Kähler metric.

Comment: Uh ok. So when you talk about potential are you talking about $\mathcal{K}$ and when you talk about metric are you talking about $\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\mathcal{K}$? I just googled those to see the picture better? Because the sentence you wrote "the potential on complex scalars" is a bit new to me.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: Yes, if $K(\phi,\bar\phi)$ is the (Kähler) potential, then the Kähler metric it induces is given by $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi^i}\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar\phi^j}K$.

Answer (score -3):

Natural -
I take it to mean you can reasonable accept it as reasonable method to explain things within a reasonable scope. The orders of magnitude seem acceptable and the outcomes seem probable.

Unnatural -
Would be mean one can't wrap ones mind around the method comfortably it is seems unreasonable. For example in the terms of scales. The orders of magnitude seem off. For example when examining gravity as compared to the weak force. In particle physics, the most important hierarchy problem is the question that asks why the weak force is $10^{32}$ times stronger than gravity. Often added dimension of space and or time are needed to find a reasonableness of explanation.

Let's use a story from link below to catch the concept of Naturalness.

http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-hierarchy-problem/naturalness/

"The Notion of “Natural” and “Unnatural”

I think the concept of naturalness is best illuminated by a bit of story-telling.

A couple of friends of mine from college (I’ll call them Ann and Steve) got married, and now have two teenage children. Back when their kids were younger — say, 4 and 7 years old — they were pretty wild. They often played rough, got mad at each other, threw things, and generally needed at lot of supervision.

One day, Ann bought some beautiful flowers and put them in her favorite glass vase. But before she put the vase on the kitchen table, the doorbell rang. She ran to the front, carrying the vase, and as she made her way to the door, she absent-mindedly put the vase down on the small, rickety table that sits by the wall of the kids’ play room.

Half an hour later, Steve returned home with the kids, and sent them into the play room to occupy themselves while he and Ann settled in from the day and prepared dinner. They heard the usual sounds: bumps and crashes, the sounds of bouncing balls and falling blocks, yells of “no fair” and “ow! stop that!”, a moment of screaming that blissfully stopped almost as soon as it started…

It was forty-five minutes later when Ann noticed the vase with the flowers wasn’t on the kitchen table. After a moment searching the kitchen and dining room, she suddenly realized that she’d put it down and forgotten it in the most dangerous place in the house.

So she went running into the play room, hoping she wasn’t too late. And what do you think she found when she opened the door?

Guess. You get three options (Figure 1). Choose the most plausible.

The vase was exactly where she’d left it, comfortably placed at the center of the table.
The vase was smashed, and the flowers crushed, down on the floor.
The vase was hanging off the table, right at the edge, within a millimeter of disaster."

[image]

"Well, the answer is #3. There it was, just hanging there.

Somehow I suspect you don’t believe me. Or at least, if you do believe me, you probably are assuming there must be some complicated explanation that I’m about to give you as to how this happened. It can’t possibly be that two young kids were playing wildly in the room and somehow managed to get the vase into this extremely precarious position just by accident, can it? For the vase to end up just so — not firmly on the table, not falling off the table, but just in between — that’s … that’s not natural!

There must (mustn’t there?) be an explanation.

Maybe there was glue on the side of the table and the vase stuck to it before falling off? Maybe one of the kids was hiding behind the table and holding the vase there as a practical joke on his mom? Maybe her husband had somehow tied a string around the vase and attached it to the table, or to the ceiling, so that the vase couldn’t fall off?  Maybe the table and vase are both magnetized somehow…?

Something so unnatural as that can’t just end up that way on its own… especially not in a room with two young children playing rough and throwing things around."

Comment: You do not answer the question at all

Comment: How does this answer my question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I said - "I take it to mean you can reasonable accept it as reasonable method to explain things within a reasonable scope. The orders of magnitude seem acceptable and the outcomes seem probable." Isn't this what you are saying that Kahler Geometry does for supergarvity theory. It's a reasonable mathematical method for setting up the target space of a collection of scalar field with reasonable magnitudes and scope and probable outcomes which can be used to explain supegravity. Your point on structure is well taken but it produces my reasonable outcomes.

Comment: There are two distinct notions of naturalness floating around. One is that of the naturalness of a mathematical structure, which is what is meant here. The other is the notion of "physical naturalness" that you try to describe in this answer. The latter arises when talking about the expected orders of magnitude for coupling constants, for instance, but that's not at all what is meant here.

Comment: @ACuriousMind No I take it to cover Kahler Geometry methodology as well as I am referring to a method with reasonable scope and the outcomes within reasonable magnitudes and probable result sets. Back stepping these reasonable outcomes of expected magnitudes would imply scalar sets that reasonable describe a hyperbolic {manifolds} topology that attempts to cover supergravity theory, Kahler geometry just fits these outcomes.

Comment: Beyond-Formulas - I will send you some good links when I have some time. It certainly answers your question as perceived. It is unfortunate at this time you don't see it. I will think harder and deeper and to explain later.

Comment: @CuriousMind By the way I am referring to "Mathemathical Naturalness"  Minimizing esoteric undercutting works better than vinegar.

Comment: @StarDrop9 I will wait for the links since I'm pretty interested in what you are trying to explain.

Comment: http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-hierarchy-problem/naturalness/     http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.5430v2.pdf   http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.92.084029    http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0503160.pdf  http://theory.fnal.gov/seminars/slides/2013/MFarina.pdf   Enjoy.

Comment: None of your links refers to mathematical naturalness, which is wholly different from physical naturalness. For naturalness in mathematics, see http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-10434-8_14 or http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical